# DynamoDB: How is read/write capacity calculated and what does it mean (for the free tier) if it is scaled quickly?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-billing

So I have been working on a couple Lambda functions for a Alexa skills including DynamoDB (actually 5 tables each with 5 RCU/WCU. I am on the free tier and I haven't used the work-in-progress functions for a couple of days, but today I realized in the cost overview that I have used about 9000 hours and will possibly use about 12000 at the end of the month. See here:

[image]

So was wondering why?
I know that you reserve the hourly capacity. And since none of the skills is live, I sticked with 5 RCU/WCU for each table (it says 25 RCU/WCU is okay for the free tier). But these numbers doesn't make sense?

Or do they? 
And the question is what happens when I scale this down to 1 RCU/WCU when all the skills go live?

I know that this would mean that only one request per second can be processed, but I am sure that this would be enough for the skills (at least for the first couple of month) - I guess that I won't have more than 200-300 monthly users. Will this significantly reduce the above numbers? Or will I be charged huge bill for some reason I don't understand after going though the documentation?

Answer (score 2):

The numbers **do** make sense, and yet you appear to be safely within the free tier.

The problem is in understanding the dimensions.

The page you are viewing shows capacity unit *hours*.

25 CU-hours *per hour* × 744 hours per month ≈ 18,600 CU-hours *per month* of each type (read, write) that are allowed in the free tier.

This number (18,600) is consistent with the percentage calculations shown: 12151 ÷ 18600 ≈ 65%, as indicated.

> *and will possibly use about 12000 at the end of the month*

Slightly more than that. You need to add the regional numbers together, so 12151 + 2177 is your projected total, which is ~78% of the total allowed.

You don't appear to need to scale anything down at this point.